# How to set method priority in order to update Java-Gnome GUI components from a worker thread at runtime

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, gtk, gnome

I have a Java-Gnome GUI that is initialised like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gtk.init(args);
    new GTK();
    Gtk.main();
}

public GTK() {
    initUI(this);
    //Exit GUI cleanly if close pressed
    connect(this);
    showAll();
}

public void initUI(final GTK gtk) {
    //Add various panes, boxes, buttons etc...
    //All my UI updates made at runtime here work correctly

    start.connect(new Button.Clicked(){

    @Override
    public void onClicked(Button start){
    worker = new worker(fileList, gtk);
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(worker);
    workerThread.start();

    Glib.idleAdd(new Handler(){
    public boolean run(){

    progress = worker.getProgress();

    if(progress != 1){
        progressBar.setFraction(progress);
        return true;
    }
    else{
          progressBar.setFraction(progress);
          return false;
                }
             }
         });
            }
    });
}
```

Where progressBar is a component in my GUI (org.gnome.gtk.ProgressBar) but the progressBar does not update until everything has finished running, it seems like it gets put on the back of the queue though and simply executes at the end as opposed to immediately as I was hoping.

http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/NEWS.html

[http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/glib/Glib.html#idleAdd(org.gnome.glib.Handler)](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/glib/Glib.html#idleAdd%28org.gnome.glib.Handler%29)

Edit.

My worker thread spans two classes the first:

```
public class auCDtect implements Runnable { 

private String processingLog;
private String output;
private String summary;
private Collection<String> fileList;
private double progress = 0.0;
private GTK gtk;

auCDtect(Collection<String> fileList, GTK gtk){this.fileList = fileList; this.gtk = gtk;}

public void run () {

    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("./auCDtect");
    command.add("-d");
    command.add("-m10");

    //Add each song passed to this class to the auCDtect command
    for(String file:fileList){

        command.add(file);
    }
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = processBuilder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Set up error stream thread 
        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR", this); 

        //Set up output stream thread
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", this); 

        // Start error and input stream threads
        new Thread(errorGobbler).start(); 
        new Thread(outputGobbler).start(); 
  }

public void update(double progress, String processingLog, String output, String summary){

    this.processingLog = processingLog;
    this.output = output;
    this.summary = summary;
    this.progress = progress/(fileList.size());
    gtk.setOutputUpdated(true);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public double getProgress(){

    return progress;
}

public String getProcessingLog(){

    return processingLog;
}

public String getOutput(){

    return output;
}

public String getSummary(){

    return summary;
}
```

}

and the second spawned by the 1st:

```
public class StreamGobbler implements Runnable { 

InputStream inputStream; 
String type;
private String processingLog = null;
private String output = null;
private String summary = null;
protected boolean finished = false;
private auCDtect auCDtect;
private int progress = 0;

StreamGobbler(InputStream inputStream, String type, auCDtect auCDtect){this.inputStream = inputStream; this.type = type; this.auCDtect = auCDtect;} 

public void run(){ 

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);

    while (((scanner.hasNextLine())&&(type == "OUTPUT"))){

        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        if(line.contains("Processing file:")){
            processingLog = line.substring(line.indexOf("P"), (line.indexOf("]")+1));
        }
        if(line.contains("This track looks like")){
            output = line.substring(line.indexOf("This track"), (line.indexOf("%")+1));
            progress = progress + 1;
        }
        if(line.contains("These")){
            summary = line.substring(line.indexOf("These tracks"));
        }

        if((type == "OUTPUT")&&(progress > 0)){

            auCDtect.update(progress, processingLog, output, summary);
            processingLog = null;
            output = null;
            summary = null;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this applies to the java version, I'm more used to the C version, but anyway...

It should not be the worker thread that tries to update the main thread, but the reverse. From the callback handling the `clicked` signal, you should call `idleAdd`, and create and run your worker thread. In the worker thread, you update a variable to which the main thread will have access, and where you will put the progress value. Then, the main loop will run the idle handler once in a while, and will read that value. It will then update the progress bar, but what is important is that this call is done from the main thread.

GTK is not thread-safe, as most toolkits (the java version may be close to be thread safe, but I'm not 100% sure, and subsequent changes done in GTK may break this in the future, so I would not rely on it). Therefore, your worker thread should not mess with user-interface components.

Take this with a grain of salt, I know a bit GTK in C, not java-gnome, so I may be completely wrong, which the `idleAdd` documentation seems to confirm anyway.

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you're saying but I'm not quite sure how that would be implemented. So I've added the signal handler that spawns a worker thread to my original question.

Whereabouts would I put the idleAdd method?

Comment: In `onClicked`, after the thread creation, call `idleAdd`. Your `idleAdd` handler should call `workerThread.getProgress()`, `progressBar.setFraction(progress)`and then return `true` to allow it to be called again at next idle event. When the work is 100% done, just return false from the idle handler, to mean you don't want it to be called anymore. Each time you return from a callback, the GTK event loop gets a chance to process pending events, like updating widgets state in the user interface.

Comment: Okay updated my method as (I think) you've described and edited my question again accordingly but I'm still getting the same problem of the progress just updating at the end when everything else has finished running

Comment: Then that may be something else that is keeping the main thread busy and preventing the main loop from doing its work. From the doc, your first implementation should have worked, but that's the only GTK binding I'm aware where it is the case, that why I told you how to do it another way. I just noticed your worker thread has a `filelist` and `gtk` arguments. What are these ? Are you manipulating GTK objects in the worker thread ? What happens if you replace the work from the worker thread with a simple `sleep` of 1 second and return an incremented counter to simulate the progress value ?

Comment: You're right it does seem like the problem is elsewhere... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I find that if I add Thread.sleep(100) to my worker thread in the method where I'm updating the progress value then everything works as intended. Isn't this in effect pausing my worker thread so that my GUI can update and then continuing it though?

That seems to defeat the point of multithreading somewhat?

Comment: Use Thread.sleep(2000) to pause for 2 seconds. 100ms isn't enough to notice if things block. You need to replace the current processing in your thread with that. If your GUI is still responsive, then your problem is in the current processing in your thread.

Comment: You really should post the code of what you're doing in your worker thread, as it's hard to know what happens out of the blue. You look to interact with some GTK widgets in a heavy way. I suppose this completely fills the GTK event loop which is processed in the main thread, blocking the UI.

Comment: I've added the entire worker thread to the question so you can have a look at it